# Как для разных объектов на сцене задать отдельные фрагментные шейдеры?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Как для разных объектов на сцене (наборов вертексов) задать отдельные (свои для каждого, допустим "типа" объекта) фрагментные шейдеры?

Есть несколько типов объектов на сцене (которые должны отобразиться), но ведь один объект вообще текстур не имеет, второй cube-текстуры, третий три текстуры и т.д. Писать универсальный шейдер - как я где-то прочитал, неверно, т.к. if-ы вставлять во фрагментый шейдер очень плохо, падает скорость.

Просьба на пальцах пояснить, "Как для разных объектов дать разные фрагментные шейдеры"?, или делать мего-шейдер-универсал.

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто.

Вы можете скомпилировать множество шейдерных программ, каждая со своей парой вертексного и фрагментного шейдера. Обычно они не повторяются, т.к. из вертексного шейдера во фрагментный передается уникальный набор параметров. Если же у вас стандартный вертексный шейдер, а фрагментные отличаются лишь кодом (набор параметров одинаковый), то вы можете скомпилировать множество пар используя один вертексный с разными фрагментными шейдерами.

Далее, рисуете каждый объект со своим шейдером (шейдерной программой). По отдельности.

Или, если в каждом типе несколько объектов, то выставляете шейдер, отрисовываете все объекты использующие его, меняете шейдер, отрисовываете другой тип объектов, и т.д.

Comment: Мне не до конца ясно, как тогда обрабатываются "перекрытия" если два объекта рендерятся по отдельности, но они друг друга перекрывают, тоесть Объект 1 переекрывает Объект 2 и наоборот ( сложной формы объекты). На каком этапе будет определена видимость/невидимость части объектов? Ведь если мы пересылаем вертексы сначала только для одного объекта, выполняем шейдерную программу , отрисовываем, переключаем программу, передаем вертексы для второго объекта, отрисовываем, то второй объект "какбы" наложиться на первый, т.к. он полностью отрисуется последним.

Comment: @AndreyL Это другой вопрос. Да, так все и будет происходить, и "большой" проблемы в этом нет. Если же это становится слишком накладно, то применяются техники сортировки и отрисовки непрозрачной геометрии спереди-назад, разбиения пространства и Occlusion Culling, для минимазиции пере-отрисовки.